# Reading key value of NSDictionary set with NSJSONSerialization of JSON data in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

So I make a simple GET request to our servers and the response code I have is as follows:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
      {
          NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSLog(@"dataString: %@", dataString);

          NSData *jsonData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSDictionary *jsonContent = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

          NSNumber * success = (NSNumber *)[jsonContent objectForKey: @"user_records_exist"];
          if([success boolValue] == YES)
          {
              NSLog(@"true");
              NSLog(@"success: %d", [success boolValue]);
          } else {
              NSLog(@"false");
              NSLog(@"failure: %d", [success boolValue]);
          }
      }] resume];
```

And the logs I get are as follows:

```
dataString: "{\"user_records_exist\": true}"

false
failure: 0
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong. How can I get the value for the `"user_records_exist"` key?

Thank you

Comment: try this `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[jsonResponse objectforKey:@"user_records_exist"]];`

Comment: if([success boolValue] == YES) Why have the explicit equality check? Just write "if([success boolValue])"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this code:

```
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"dataString: %@", dataString);

NSData *jsonData = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Get your response dictionary from your original data:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                     completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
      {
          NSDictionary *jsonContent = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

          BOOL success = [[jsonContent objectForKey: @"user_records_exist"] boolValue];
          if(success)
          {
              NSLog(@"true");
              NSLog(@"success: %d", success);
          } else {
              NSLog(@"false");
              NSLog(@"failure: %d", success);
          }
      }] resume];
```

Comment: When I try your solution the log for `NSLog(@"jsonResponse: %@", jsonResponse);` becomes `(null)`

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly shows that you are trying to get the objectforkey for a string instead of dictionary.

```
    NSDictionary *jsonContent = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

Comment: problem not in the `Serialization`

Comment: don't do this, because it's just hiding your original error - that your data is giving you a string and not a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

--->dataString: "{\"user_records_exist\": true}"

**It is not dictionary key it is string Please improve it your server api in dictionary key formate Otherwise your app will be crashed. After make dictionary key it will work and you can check as this**

```
id jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

NSLog(@"jsonResponse: %@", jsonResponse);

If( [jsonResponse isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] )
{

 Bool userRecord =  [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"user_records_exist"]boolValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `jsonResponse` as you are assuming is a NSDictionary, actually it is a NSString. Since strings don't respond to the valueForKey: method your app crashed. That is what the error message is telling you.